# How does the assembler translate english assembly to binary machine code instructions?

Tags: assembly

**My assumptions** (please correct me if anything in this part is wrong including wrong usages of jargons)

In MIPS instructions, `add t1 t2 t3` translates to `00000001010010110100100000100000` . The `add, t1, t2, t3` I suppose first of all get translated to some ASCII value implemented on the hardware level. For example,  `t1` is `116 049` in binary by the ASCII convention. But then, these ASCII values gotta map to the instruction. Per the MIPS op code specification, `add` corresponds to the last 6 `100000` bits, `t1` corresponds to the `01001` bits in the middle, etc.

**Question**

Assuming my assumptions are correct, how exactly does the assembler take the `116 049` and map it to `01001`? In this course called nand2tetris, I've been writing an assembler in C which is really just a text parser. Obviously, C gets translated to assembly, so the actual assembler has no access to it. Thus came the confusion.

Comment: The assembler parses the assembly source code, and outputs the corresponding machine code. You mention that you are writing an assembler right now, so you'll do it yourself soon. It's really not a big problem.

Comment: I don't understand how the following sentence relates to your question: "Obviously, C gets translated to assembly, so the actual assembler has no access to it." Your C code is eventually translated to machine code. The machine code implements your C code. How this happens is not so important, since you are promised that the resulting executable is a faithful interpretation of your original program.